# Can CS5 run on OS X 10.7.5?

Tags: macos

I've been avoiding updating my OS because I didn't want to lose the use of older applications. I just bought a new Airport Extreme which requires OS X 10.7.5 or later. I'm currently running OS X 10.6.8 and need to know if I upgrade will it run Creative Suite CS5?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running CS5 on Yosemite right now, (Photoshop is running right now, in fact,) and have had CS5 run on OS Xs all the way back to Snow Leopard or earlier:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See [adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/mac-os-mavericks-compatability.html) for details:

> Adobe Photoshop CS5, CS4, and CS3 were also tested with Mac OS X Mavericks and there are currently no known major issues.

So it's probably safe to assume that CS5 will work with 10.7.x as well. To be on the safe side, you should make a full system backup before upgrading and test CS5 afterwards (*before* you start to use it for real).